# Why doesn't this array check work?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to check an array for a 1 or a 3, if either is found, print false, else print true. I ahve this:

```
if(array[i] == 1){
 bool = false;
}
else if(array[i] == 3){
 bool = false;
}
else{
 bool = true; 
}
```

However it does not work in all cases.

If the input is `0 2 4` it prints true as it should.

but if the input is `4 2 7 1 8` it should be false as there is a 1, but it prints true.

What am i doing wrong?

EDIT: Added a break to the if and changed the if statement. Works now.

```
 if(array[i] == 1 || array[i] == 3){
     bool = false;
     break;
    }
    else{
     bool = true; 
    }
```

Comment: Assuming that this is done in some kind of loop, once you find `1` or `3` you should use `break` to break out of the loop, otherwise, unless the last value is a `1` or `3` `bool` will always be `true`...

Comment: is this code inside a loop? you're probably overwriting `bool` each time, so the result at the end only reflects whether the last number is a 1 or 3.

Comment: You can also shorten your `if` statement using `||` (or), something like `if(array[i] == 1 || array[i] == 3){...} else {...}`

Comment: yes its in a for loop, and @MadProgrammer I have done it that way but I wrote it this way too.

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks, I added the break, works now.

Answer (score 3):

A better approach is

```
boolean flag = true;

for(int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++)
{
    if(myArray[i]==1 || myArray[i]==3){
        flag = false;
        break;
    }
}

return flag;
```

Answer (score 0):

this code

```
if(array[i] == 1 || array[i] == 3){
     bool = false;
     break;
    }
    else{
     bool = true; 
    }
```

equal

```
if(array[i] == 1){
     bool = false;
    }else{
     bool = true; 
    }
    if(array[i] == 3){
     bool = false;
    }
    else{
     bool = true; 
    }
```